# How to view Visual Studio 2015 Javascript Console after debugging mode stops?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

My Javascript Apache Cordova app builds fine but doesn't behave debugging on the emulator or real device.

I see a bunch of messages rush by in the Visual Studio Javascript Console but the app then immediately crashes and the Javascript Console becomes unavailable.

I've tried setting breakpoints to pause the app which doesn't work.

How can I view these Javascript Console logs after the debugger stops ?

EDIT: this if for Windows Phone (Universal) with plugins for Windows Phone and not debuggable in the browser

Comment: try this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn688631.aspx

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work in VS either. But [Chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en) should get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the only way i've figured ;

1. Ensure JS console button "Clear on navigate" is **not** set
2. Start the app so that the errors appear albeit momentarily
3. Remove plugins and associated code one by one until your app doesn't crash
4. View original error messages in the JS console from previous sessions

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question but it may help to check the exception settings via:

Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings

They determine whether or not the debugger will break when exceptions are thrown.